# One of the inline-block divs raises (inside a paren div)

Tags: html, alignment, css

This is my problem:

I have one parent div with 3 inner divs.
Inner divs are "display:inline-block".
Inside each inner div there is a text div "height:60px".
One of those text divs has 3 lines of text and this raises that whole inner div.

Why is this happening? Why aren't inner divs aligned?

Pic of the problem (3D inspector): http://i203.photobucket.com/albums/aa1/GuillermoRGTMU/problem.jpg

CSS:

```
#PARENT{
text-align:center;
margin-bottom:20px;
}

#INNER_DIV{
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
width:180px;
height:150px;
margin:auto 5px;
background-color:#68adf3;
}

#TEXT_DIV{
height:60px;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

> ```
>   <div id="PARENT">
>       <div id="INNER_DIV">
>          <div id="TEXT_DIV">Matrícula abierta</div>
>       </div>
>       <div id="INNER_DIV">
>          <div id="TEXT_DIV">Cocina casera</div>
>       </div>
>       <div id="INNER_DIV">
>          <div id="TEXT_DIV">Jornada simple/completa Hora matinera/tardama Supermegatardana</div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the vertical align of the inline blocks, like this:

```
#INNER_DIV{
...
vertical-align:middle;
...
}
```